# How to switch which fragments ViewPager displays

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

Stuck on this for a while; I would really appreciate some help.

I have a ViewPager which displays photos and meta data about them (Fragment1). If the user clicks on a photo, I would like to switch to a full screen view (Fragment2). Here's the thing, once the user swipes from Fragment2, the next view should also load Fragment2, not Fragment1 again.

I would like to do this at the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, as it already knows the List of objects to display.

To clarify again: If I swipe from Fragment1, I should see another Fragment1. If I swipe from Fragment2, I should see another Fragment2. If I hit Back while in Fragment2(somePosition), it should load Fragment1(somePosition).

Thanks!

Comment: Add some code what have you done so far then i can help

Comment: Try using fragmenttransitions. Documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your pager adpater :

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
       if(mFragment1 == null){
            mFragment1 = new Fragment2();
       }
       return mFragment1();
    } else if (position == 1) {
         if(mFragment2 == null){
             mFragment2 = new Fragment2();
         }
         return mFragment2;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
For changing the fragment use this code in your click listner :

```
 mPager.setCurrentItem(1); // 0 = first fragment, 1 = secnd fragment
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: I think this would show Fragment2 when position==0 and Fragment1 when position==1.  I want to always show Fragment1, until you click on the image, then start showing Fragment2. Does that make sense?

Comment: when your pos is 0 it show your first fragment and about the onclick i will upadte my answer